# Highchart multiple axes - sync axes on multiple charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've two Highcharts with multiple axes. The two set of axes represents the same units and the two charts are horizontal aligned. I've created a JSFiddle to illustrate my setup based on a [Highchart sample](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes):

http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/gbbzz2jh/

[image: Highchart multi axes sample]

In this example you can zoom on the y axis on the chart to the left. Please note that the axes on the right chart are synchronized. That's done using this `afterSetExtremes` event:

```
function syncYAxis(e) {
    var thisAxis = this;
    var thisChart = e.currentTarget.chart;

    Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
        if (chart && chart !== thisChart) {
            var currentAxis = chart.get(thisAxis.options.id);
            currentAxis.setExtremes(e.min, e.max);
        }
    });
}
```

If I change the right chart to a different Highchart, that does no longer work. See this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/kmuhw0zf/

I've tried to debug and added a `afterSetExtremes` event to the right chart axes:

```
function rightChartAxisChanged(e) {
    var thisAxis = this;
    console.log('Right chart axis changed: '+thisAxis.options.id);
    console.log('min/max: '+e.min+','+e.max);
    console.log('user min/max: '+e.userMin+','+e.userMax);
}
```

From what I can see, it seems that the new min/max values in `e.min` and `e.max` are computed wrong. The correct values that I've given in the `setExtremes` call in the `syncYAxis`, are stored in the `e.userMin` and `e.userMax`.

Comment: So in the second fiddle you have provided when i zoomed the first highchart the second one also zoomed in.. That means they are in sync. Can you tell me what excatly you want to syncronize

Comment: Seems to working properly also for me. Could you desribe what is incorrect / doesn't work or how we can replicate your issue, step by step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I tried your demo ( http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/kmuhw0zf/ ) - it works fine, except sometimes it fails. Anyway, I would improve logic with `tickPositioner` for the second chart: so ticks will always get the same numbers as in the first one, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/kmuhw0zf/3/

```
        tickPositioner: function () {
            return $('#chart1').highcharts().get('axis1').tickPositions.slice();
        },
        id: 'axis1',
```

Additionally, you can set `alignTicks` to false, so it will prevent Highcharts logic to force ticks at specific places.

And regarding `e.min`/`e.max` vs `a.userMin`/`e.userMax` - you can set for example max = 32.1235 and this will be stored in `e.userMax`, but chart will render max = 35 (for a nice tick number), so `e.max` will be 35. Note, that for me your both demos works fine (except issue with `alignTicks`).